# Resolving static methods and protected classes on Spring Boot auto configuration report

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to make my application lighter by manually specifying needed configurations instead of relying on auto configuration, as explained [here](http://www.alexecollins.com/spring-boot-performance/). The thing is that my "Positive matches" report is 451 lines long. My first question is, will I really gain anything noticeable, given the amount of things to import anyway?

Then, when trying to run a script through the abovementioned report to produce a list of classes to `@Import`, I see that there are many (in my case 66) references to static methods, of the type:

```
   AuditAutoConfiguration#authenticationAuditListener matched
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AbstractAuthenticationEvent (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.actuate.security.AbstractAuthenticationAuditListener; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

Not all of these static methods are directly called after the type that they return, so I have to go through the list manually. So, is there any way of getting the type instead of the static method name in the report?

And finally, there are protected elements in the report, as

```
   AuditAutoConfiguration.AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration matched
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

`AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration` has protected access, so I can't impor it. Will it be enough importing the containing class, in this case `AuditAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: In my opinion, the advice in the linked article isn't generally applicable and for many applications should be ignored. You say you want to make your application lighter. What have you measured that makes you think it's too heavy?